# urban airship - sending Broadcast message using Json

Tags: javascript, json, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to send a broadcast message using a std. html/javascript to Android devices. I have found a script here on stackoverflow but i can't get it to work. it returns no errors. Then a send a message from urban airship admin i works fine. Is i missing something here??

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">

var ruleObj = {
    "android": {"alert": "test"}
}
;

var objStr = JSON.stringify(ruleObj);
// username : Application Key;
// password : Application Master Secret;

    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){ 

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        username: "qE.........",
        password: "zp........",
        url:"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/",
        data: objStr,
        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: "it returns no errors." You're actually missing the `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` function that is called if the ajax request fails. Within that function you can grab the specific error. `jQuery.ajax()` docs for reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server doesn't add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header the AJAX call will then fail the "same origin policy", and the query will be denied.

The normal way around this is to modify your URL so jQuery will attempt to use JSONP instead of plain JSON.

You can do this in two ways:

```
url: "https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/?callback=?"
```

or by adding:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried to add the ? and now i get an HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed error. In UA. troubleshooting guide (https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60923-troubleshooting-http-status-codes) it should be something to do with the /. But I’m using this url it should be ok :  url:"?https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/"

Comment: just add `dataType: 'jsonp'` to your parameters, and it _should_ then append the correct parameter for you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi Again. Have added the datatype: 'json'. My firebug returns : Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="parsererror"} parsererror jQuery161013864902217729813_1320224386941 was not called. I'm a little desperate. is there anyone who has a working example that works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```

You will also want to use the statusCode parameter. Since you will not be getting valid JSON back, you need to instead check the status code that is passed back to determine if you call was a success:

```
statusCode: {
    200: function() {
        alert('message sent!');
    },
    500: function(  ) {
        alert('500 error');
    }
}
```