# How do you send a notification from server using UrbanAirship?

Tags: push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am trying to send a notification from the server and the [docs](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Server:+Android+Push+API) says to POST to /api/push/broadcast/ which I have done from the following code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/?callback=?',
    data: '{"android": {"alert": "hi"}}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    username:"P4...UBg",
    password:"fg...gDA",
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // log the error to the console
            alert(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        },
});
```

And I am getting a 500 (Internal Server Error). I added the callback to prevent "same origin policy" error as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967708/urban-airship-sending-broadcast-message-using-json). Does anybody know how to do it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I initially tried to set things up this way (making a raw $POST) to their servers. In the end, I was happy to find that they have modules for most common languages. Our server is all written in Python so we used the Python module. Here is a list of the packages they have:

https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60713-push-server-libraries

All we had to do was upload the .py file into our bin and we're able to send pushes like this:

```
airship_android = urbanairship.Airship(SECRET_KEY, MASTER_KEY)
push_data = {"android": {"alert": notification_message, "extra": str(extra_data_str)}, "apids": [apid]}
airship_android.push(push_data)
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I am using Windows Azure as my server and unfortunately I need to send it via JavaScript